# how to get the list of accounts from Contact

Tags: soql

i have list of Accountids .now i am query the contact based on list of AccountIds for this one i create one for loop ..how we can get the `Map<Id,List<Account>>`

```
Map<Id,List<Account>> mapcon = new Map<Id,List<Account>>();
List<Account> acclist = new List<Account>();

for(Contact con:[select id,Accountid from contact where Accountid in:Accountid]){
    acclist.add(con.Accountid);
    mapcon.put(con.id,acclist);
}
```

The problem is here i am get the Accountid in acclist...i want instead of Accounid how to get the list of Accounts ..any help 
Thanks
Venki

Comment: So you have a list of Accounts and want to get all of their Contacts?

Comment: If you have a list of Account Ids, why are you querying Contacts to get a map of Accounts? Are you only looking for Accounts with Contacts?

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right way. If you want to add account objects instead of ID's just use the reference name `Account`

```
for(Contact con:[Select Id, Account.Id, Account.Name, Acount.PesrsonEmail, Account.LastName 
                 From Contact 
                 Where Accountid IN:Accountid]){

    acclist.add(con.Account);
}
```

BUT, the relationship between Contact and Account [is n-1](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm) so one Account can have many Contacts and i think you can not get a *list* of accounts belongs to a contact.